# Count Field Incorrect error with Sybase OLEDB driver through SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, oledb, sybase, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating multiple temp tables in a set of queries in SSRS before arriving at the final result that I want to display.

This works fine as long as I use **select into** to create my temp tables, but starts failing when I changed this to a set of **create table** and **insert into** statements.

I checked other resources on web, and most of them suggest either I am using bind variables wrong, or I am using a reserved keyword somewhere. I have thoroughly checked, and this is not the case.

I also checked the ASE documentation on SQL batches, and it states that create table statements are allowed in batches.

```
create table #temp1 (col1 char(9))
insert into #temp1 select col1 from existing_table1
set sort_merge off
select col2,col3 into #temp2 from #temp1 a, existing_table2 b where a.col1 = b.col1
set sort_merge on
select col2, col3 from #temp2
```

The error that I get is as below:

> An error has occurred during report processing (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query Execution failed for dataset dataset1. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   [07002][Native Code 30070][ASEOLEDB]COUNT field incorrect

Comment: Why not create CREATE @TABLE (@MyValue INT)... Temp tables disappear with scope.

Comment: Because the db in which I can create table is open to all users, and there is a chance (however slight) that a table of same name might already exist. If I write an if block to check for table's existence before dropping, the SSRS won't be able to drop the table since it fires all statements as a part of a batch, and blocks (such as if) do not get executed properly in batches.